# WebView Scroll Down on Orientation Change?

Tags: android, webview, orientation

Okay if I'm at the very top of a page in WebView and change the orientation on my phone it has issues, but if I'm even 2 pixels down from the top it works fine, So my question, can I make it automatically scroll down a few pixels on orientation change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the methods `scrollBy(int x, int y)` or `scrollTo(int x, int y)`. However, I would strongly recommend figuring out why your phone has issues when you change the orientation.